# Changing the XML template with SQL Server and saving to a directory

Tags: sql-server, xml, replace

I need to create 1 XML file with my data in 2 different tables in SQL.

To do this I have the following 4 step T-SQL code. But I'm not sure if this is the right way?

1. I pull the data from the tables and throw it to a variable.
2. I'm assigning the XML template to a variable as `@xmlTemplate`.
3. I replace the data that I wrote in the XML template between the {data} tags.
4. I save `@xmlTemplate`, which I changed with my data, in a directory as `newXmlFile.xml`.

I saw that there are methods such as `OPENROWSET`, `OPENXML` in SQL. Is there a more accurate way to place my data in my table into XML template?

My code

```
------------------------------------ 1) areas to change and Data to be processed on the xml template.
DECLARE @UUID            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
        @IssueDate       NVARCHAR(10),
        @InvoiceTypeCode NVARCHAR(5)

SELECT @UUID = newid(),
       @IssueDate = '2020-12-30',
       @InvoiceTypeCode = 'SALES'

------------------------------------ 2) Define Xml Template
DECLARE @xmlTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @xmlTemplate = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="general.xslt"?>
<Invoice
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
    xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
    xmlns:ubltr="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:TurkishCustomizationExtensionComponents"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd"
    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent/>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
    <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
    <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
    <cbc:ProfileID>TICARIFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
    <cbc:ID/>
    <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
    <cbc:UUID>{UUID}</cbc:UUID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>{IssueDate}</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>{InvoiceTypeCode}</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
    <cbc:Note>Sicil No: 33333, İşletme Merkezi: İstanbul</cbc:Note>
    <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>USD</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
    <cbc:AccountingCost/>
    <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric>

    <cac:Signature>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN_TCKN">11111111111</cbc:ID>
        <cac:SignatoryParty>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">111111111</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>Mecidiyeköy</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>İSTANBUL</cbc:CityName>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:Name>TÜRKİYE</cbc:Name>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
        </cac:SignatoryParty>
        <cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
            <cac:ExternalReference>
                <cbc:URI>#Signature_AAA2018000000015</cbc:URI>
            </cac:ExternalReference>
        </cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
    </cac:Signature>
    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">11111111</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Rota 8043</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>Mecidiyeköy</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>İSTANBUL</cbc:CityName>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:Name>TÜRKİYE</cbc:Name>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:Name>SARIYER</cbc:Name>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:Contact>
                <cbc:ElectronicMail>mail@mail.com</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
                <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">1201830512</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
                <cbc:Name>Rota 8443</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
                <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>test</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
                <cbc:CityName>tes</cbc:CityName>
                <cac:Country>
                    <cbc:Name>AVUSTRALYA OKYANUSU</cbc:Name>
                </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:Name>test</cbc:Name>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>20</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
        <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2018-09-14</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
        <cbc:PaymentChannelCode>Kasa</cbc:PaymentChannelCode>
        <cbc:InstructionNote>test</cbc:InstructionNote>
        <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <cbc:ID>123</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:CurrencyCode>USD</cbc:CurrencyCode>
        </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
    <cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="USD">1.00</cbc:Amount>
    </cac:AllowanceCharge>
    <cac:PricingExchangeRate>
        <cbc:SourceCurrencyCode>USD</cbc:SourceCurrencyCode>
        <cbc:TargetCurrencyCode>TRY</cbc:TargetCurrencyCode>
        <cbc:CalculationRate>5</cbc:CalculationRate>
    </cac:PricingExchangeRate>
    <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">1.62</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="USD">9.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">1.62</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:Percent>18</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                    <cbc:Name>KDV</cbc:Name>
                    <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
    </cac:TaxTotal>
    <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="USD">10.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="USD">9.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="USD">10.62</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="USD">1.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="USD">0.00</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="USD">0</cbc:PayableRoundingAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="USD">10.62</cbc:PayableAmount>
    </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
    <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="C62">10</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="USD">9.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0.1</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <cbc:SequenceNumeric>0</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="USD">1.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cbc:BaseAmount currencyID="USD">10.00</cbc:BaseAmount>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">1.62</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
                <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="USD">9.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
                <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="USD">1.62</cbc:TaxAmount>
                <cbc:Percent>18</cbc:Percent>
                <cac:TaxCategory>
                    <cac:TaxScheme>
                        <cbc:Name>KDV</cbc:Name>
                        <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                    </cac:TaxScheme>
                </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>1</cbc:Name>
            <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
                <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
            </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="USD">1</cbc:PriceAmount>
        </cac:Price>
    </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
'
------------------------------------ 3) Replace XML File
SET @xmlTemplate = REPLACE(@xmlTemplate, '{UUID}', @UUID)
SET @xmlTemplate = REPLACE(@xmlTemplate, '{IssueDate}', @IssueDate)
SET @xmlTemplate = REPLACE(@xmlTemplate, '{InvoiceTypeCode}', @InvoiceTypeCode)


------------------------------------ 4) Save the xml file.
DECLARE @File VARCHAR(2000) = 'c:\newXmlFile.xml'
DECLARE @OLE INT
EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream',
                    @OLE OUTPUT

EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE,
                         'Type',
                         2                           --1 = binary, 2 = text
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE,
                         'Mode',
                         3                           --0 = not set, 1 read, 2 write, 3 read/write
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE,
                         'Charset',
                         'utf-8'                     --'ISO-8859-1'
/*
EXECUTE sp_OASetProperty @OLE,
                         'LineSeparator',
                         'adLF'
*/
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,
                    'Open'

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,
                    'WriteText',
                    NULL,
                    @xmlTemplate      --text method
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,
                    'SaveToFile',
                    NULL,
                    @File,
                    2   --1 = notexist 2 = overwrite

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @OLE,
                    'Close'

EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @OLE
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing file access in SQL. C++, C#, VB.NET, Python and Java are all better options

Comment: Why are you using those ancient stored procedures? SQL Server has supported XQUERY since 2005 (iirc).

Comment: Be aware that XQuery will probably throw errors on `encoding="UTF-8"` since you're storing the XML in an nvarchar data type (which is UCS-2 encoded by default).

Comment: @larnu I will try it with xquery.I did not know that there was such a thing.

Comment: *"I did not know that there was such a thing"* Like i said, it's been around since 2005. If you're reading articles that tell you to use those old procedures, you're reading the wrong articles (and *really* old ones).